# Using and/or statement on WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to run a WP_Query using tags selected by the user. In one case, I want to get all the posts with one tag called "highlights" and filter them even more by other tags like "hockey" and "football."

So in English: `Get all posts called "highlights" AND "hockey" ... OR ... all posts tagged "highlights" AND "football"`

Using WP_QUERY I can get all tags: `WP_QUERY('tags:highlights+hockey+football')`

Or any of the tags: `WP_QUERY('tags:highlight,hockey,football')`

But I can't seem to combine and the AND with the OR.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Taxonomy Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters):

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'highlights', 'hockey' )
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'highlights', 'football' )
    )
)
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I wrote this off the Codex and haven't tested it, but it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks this was immensely helpful! I tried this but I believe the line `'terms' => array('highlights','hockey')` is an OR statement (highlights OR hockey -OR- highlights OR football). I changed `'relation'` to `AND`, put `'highlights'` in the first `terms` array and put the remaining terms in the second `terms` array and it worked!